# Regarding WPF and web development?

Tags: .net, wpf

i don't know anything about WPF. so a question has come to my mind that when we develop apps in WPF that can be run as web application without changing code. please comment. thanks.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to actually read something, somewhere about WPF as you'll quickly understand the scope of the technology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WPF runs on the client. It is what replaces WinForms. [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/) was intended for the web. It is a subset of WPF and it allows you to embed into a web page just like Flash.

For web development I would recommend you [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Answer (score 3):

WPF is the best technology for windows development. It's very easy to learn and use. Though it's not as mature as WinForms but is surely worth trying. I am developing a register maintenance application and feel like home.
You can go through following links to quickly grab this technology

1) [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)

2) [WPF Tutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

3) [WPF Sample Applications](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/default.aspx)

Best of luck and Happy Learning

Answer (score 2):

WPF is a graphic user interface technology for windows client application. So you cannot do web applications with WPF ( i'm simplying , it is not entirely true ). 
If you want to create an application that runs in a browser , you can use Silverlight which is a different solution.
So to sum up. If you want to create a software like photoshop , use WPF.
if you want to make a website ( web apps are web sites ), use Silverlight ( or javascript and HTML or Flash ... ).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the XBAP variation of WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) too. See if it fits your need.